# Installing RPy2 from source files on Windows 7

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am trying to install rpy2-2.3.1 on Windows 7, using the source files under [rpy2-2.3.1.tar.gz](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpy/files/rpy2/2.3.x/).

However, upon running `setup.py` on the command prompt, I get the trace-back below. I have checked a few stack-overflow posts on installing RPy2 on windows 7 and am already aware that it is a challenge. Does anyone have an idea what went wrong in my case?

Thanks in advance.

**P.S:** I cannot install it using the [.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpy/files/rpy2/2.3.x/) since I get the '*Python version 2.7. required, which was not found in the registry*' warning and do not have privileges to update the registry. So it is not an option for me.

**P.S2:** Before I started getting this trace-back I set up the R path as: `C:\Program Files\R\R-3.01\bin`. This I believe points to a 64-bit R. May this be causing the problem?

```
I:\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MyProject\rpy2-2.3.1>C:/Python27/python.exe setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 463, in <module>
'rpy2': ['doc/source/rpy2_logo.png', ]}
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
dist.run_commands()
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
self.run_command(cmd)
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
self.run_command('build')
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 971, in run_command
cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
File "C:\u\windows\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
self.finalize_options()
File "setup.py", line 163, in finalize_options
config += get_rconfig(r_home, about)
File "setup.py", line 333, in get_rconfig
rc = RConfig.from_string(rconfig, allow_empty = allow_empty)
File "setup.py", line 293, in from_string
+ '\nin string\n' + string)
ValueError: Invalid substring

in string
```

Answer (score 0):

This site has what you are looking for. It has a lot of good modules in .exe format:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#rpy2

Comment: thanks for your answer. But, I have already tried _rpy2-2.3.8.win-amd64-py2.7.exe_ and _rpy2-2.3.8.win32-py2.7.exe_ on the link you have given and got the same registry issue.

Comment: @Zhubard Why try rpy2-2.3.1 rather than rpy2-2.3.8 ?